# Why call to Function.apply.bind(fn, null) calls `fn.apply`, and not `Function.apply`?

Tags: javascript, bind, apply

Suppose we have this code:

```
let fn1 = Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null);
fn1([1, 10, 5]); // returns 10
```

I know that it's a `spread function` in ES6 we would instead write:

```
Math.max(...[1, 10, 5]);
```

But I can not understand how `Function.apply.bind` does its magic...

This is how I think code works, please correct me where I am wrong.

1. This statement `let fn1 = Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null);` creates a new function `Function.apply(null)` with `this` set to `Math.max` and assigns it to `fn1` variable.
2. This statement `fn1([1, 10, 5]);` invokes our newly created function in this manner: `Function.apply(null, [1, 10, 5])` with `this` inside this function set to `Math.max`. But this call is invalid... if we copy/paste that line in JS console - we will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

So, my question is - how `Function.apply` knows that it should use `this` equal to `Math.max` and "rotate"/modify its call to `Math.max.apply`?

### Updated

I just understood how all that stuff works! First, let's rewrite a code to its "real" form:

```
let fn1 = this.Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null);
this.fn1([1, 10, 5]); // returns 10
```

Magic? `this` is implicitly added to "global" methods/objects. Now let's rewrite those 2 paragraphs of text to show you how magic works :)

1. This statement `let fn1 = Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null);` creates a new function `newFunction.apply(null, ...args)`, where `newFunction == Math.max`, so it's the same as a function `Math.max.apply(null, ...args)` and assigns it to `fn1` variable.
2. This statement `fn1([1, 10, 5]);` calls `newFunction.apply(null, [1, 10, 5])`

Magic revealed :)

### Duplicate update

This question is not a duplicate of another question. It's different because it's more concrete, here I am asking specifically "Why call to Function.apply.bind(fn, null) calls `fn.apply`, and not `Function.apply`?" and not "How apply.bind works?". It's like saying that a question "Why bicycle gears use kinesthetic force of pedals and not directly generate force by acceleration?" is the same as a question "How does a bicycle work?"

Comment: *"...spread function..."* "Spread notation (or "spread syntax"). It's not a function.

Comment: I was referring to 1st code sample (2 lines of code) as a "spread function". It can not be called "spread notation" because there is no 3 dots syntax (...).

Comment: `newFunction.apply(null)` should be `(..args) => newFunction.apply(null, ...args)`. When you call `Math.max.apply(null)` you get `-Infinity`.

Comment: @marzelin, yes you are right :)

Comment: (If you see a suggested duplicate link on your question, or if your question is closed as being a duplicate, please add any responses to that **at the end**, not at the start. Questions are mostly read by new readers, not readers who've seen your earlier version, and so the first thing folks should see is _not_ meta commentary about duplicates).

Comment: @halfer, make sense, thanks!

Comment: I think the answer to the duplicate still applies here. It explains "*Calling `bind` on it [`Function.prototye.apply`] returns a special version of `apply` whose `this` is set to `Math.max`*". And when you call that, you get `apply` applied to `Math.max`, which calls `Math.max`.

Comment: Re your edit: This stuff has nothing whatsoever to do with `this` being the global object at global scope. Not remotely.

Comment: Care to explain? Preferably backup your words with reference to ECMAScript® 2015 Language Specification or at least MDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's split it into parts, first of all, [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The **bind()** method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So you are `bind`ing the `apply` method from `Function` global object to `Math.max`.

The function `fn1` returned by `bind()` is therefore equivalent to `this.apply()`, where `this` really is `Math.max`, exactly as you "asked" to the `bind()` method.

Comment: >"The function fn1 returned by bind() is therefore equivalent to this.apply()" Very interesting. Can you show me docs or some source where it is stated that "this" value, bound by "bind" function transforms regular "fn1()" call to "this.fn1()"?

Comment: If I didn't make a mistake is right there in the docs I quoted.

Comment: But please notice that I do not mean that fn1() is equivalent to this.fn1() but rather in your specific case fn1() is equivalent to this.apply() where this is Math.max, hence Math.max.apply()

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
let fn1 = Function.apply.bind(Math.max, null);
```

...is really tricky. :-) It calls `bind` on `Function.apply`, creating a function that will call `apply` with `Math.max` as the `this` value and `null` as the first argument (the *thisArg* that `apply` should use when calling `Math.max`; `Math.max` doesn't care about `this`, so `null` is fine).

When you call `fn1`, it calls `Function.apply` with `this` set to `Math.max`, and `null` as the first argument, followed by the array you pass into `fn1`. `apply` calls `Math.max` with `null` as `this` and the entries from the array as discrete arguments.

Comment: ">apply calls Math.max"    Why? Math.max is just a `this` value inside a body of `apply` function. Why does "apply" calls "Math.max"?

Comment: @yaru - Because `apply` calls the function it sees as its `this` value when you call it. A normal `apply` call looks like this: `myFunction.apply(thisArg, [arg0, arg1])`. Since `apply` is called via `myFunction.apply`, `this` during the call is `myFunction`. So using `bind` on `apply` and passing a function as the first argument (the `this` that will get bound) determines the function that `apply` calls.